# click_action not launching the specified activity

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I want to launch a specific activity when tapping a notification. I used `click_action` to try to accomplish that just like below, setting it to `FollowActivity`:

```
{
  "notification": {
    "title": "New follower!",
    "body": "{name} is following you",
    "sound": "default",
    "click_action": "FollowActivity"
  }
}
```

I also set the `intent-filter` of the activity to be launched with the same action name `FollowActivity`, just like what you can see below:

```
<activity
            android:name=".NotificationActivity"
            android:label="Notification"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FollowActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

But when notification comes in and I tap on it, `NotificationActivity` is NOT being launched. But it launch my default/activity.

What am I missing?

Comment: How are you showing the notification? Post that code.

Comment: since it is just a notification, it will be shown automatically in system tray. It will not go through to any of my code.

Comment: Um ... if you are showing a notification in the system tray, you have to do this with code. Notifications don't just show up automatically on their own. Do you not own the notification you're trying to react to?

Comment: Nope. That is not the case with FCM. If you only have notification payload. Android handles it automatically but if you have a data payload that is when FirebaseMessagingService is needed to handle and display it.

Comment: Oh, interesting - did not realize FCM did that. See my suggested answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is your JSON formatted correctly? Looking at the docs, looks like your `click_action` should be within an `android.notification` block?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#example_notification_message_with_platform-specific_delivery_options

```
{
  "message":{
     "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
     "notification":{
       "title":"Match update",
       "body":"Arsenal goal in added time, score is now 3-0"
     },
     "android":{
       "ttl":"86400s",
       "notification"{
         "click_action":"OPEN_ACTIVITY_1"
       }
     },
     "apns": {
       "headers": {
         "apns-priority": "5",
       },
       "payload": {
         "aps": {
           "category": "NEW_MESSAGE_CATEGORY"
         }
       }
     },
     "webpush":{
       "headers":{
         "TTL":"86400"
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this code snippet is for platform-specific. If you look other code before that, the "click_action" is on the notification block. If you just want to be more specific, you use the code above.

Comment: @JaysonTamayo In the documentation it says the `click_action` is specific to Android: 
"sets the appropriate keys to define the result of a user tap on the notification on Android and Apple — click_action, and category, respectively."